# Why $\sin x + \cos x$ is non-decreasing in $0 \le x \le \pi/4$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

How can I prove that $\sin x + \cos x$ is non-decreasing in $0 \le x \le \pi/4$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)=\sin x+\cos x,f'(x)=\cos x-\sin x=\sqrt2\sin\left(\dfrac\pi4-x\right)$

which will be non-negative if $-\dfrac{3\pi}4\le x\le\dfrac\pi4$ as $\sin y\ge0$ in $0\le y\le\pi$

Comment: @Drupalist,  $$f''(x)>0\implies f(x)$$ is increasing right?

Comment: Yes you are right, for a few seconds I made mistake between $f(x)$ and the $f^{''} (x)$. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$, We have,

$\sin x+\cos x=\sqrt{1+2\sin x\cos x}=\sqrt{1+\sin 2x}$

Now, we have reduced it to a single trigonometric function. I think you can continue from here.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\sin(x)+\cos(x)$

$f'(x)=\cos(x)-\sin(x)$ which is obviously nonnegative on that interval.